# Arguments passed via composeWith not found by composed generator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

Yeoman version: 1.4.8
NPM: 2.11.3
Node: 0.12.7

There's the added hiccup of the generator calling its own subgenerator, but that's not too crazy and that part works just fine.

I have this in my parent:

```
this.composeWith('mercury:component', { options: {
  component: this.props.domain + 'Content',
  domain: this.props.path + '/'
}})
```

And this in my component index:

```
constructor: function () {
  yeoman.generators.Base.apply(this, arguments);
  this.argument('component', {type: String, required: true});
  this.argument('domain', {type: String});
},
```

If I call mercury:component directly and inspect `arguments`, I see the command-line args in '0'.

```
{ '0': [ 'test', '.' ],
  '1': { env: {things...} } }
```

When it's called from the parent generator, they're properties of '1'.

```
{ '0': [],
  '1': 
   { component: 'TestContent',
     domain: 'src/domains/test/',
     env: {things...} } }
```

It then has a sad.

```
Error: Did not provide required argument component!
at null.<anonymous> (/Users/zlandon/mercury/generator-mercury/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:359:33)
at Array.forEach (native)
at Base.checkRequiredArgs (/Users/zlandon/mercury/generator-mercury/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:355:19)
at argument (/Users/zlandon/mercury/generator-mercury/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:321:8)
at new module.exports.yeoman.generators.Base.extend.constructor (/Users/zlandon/mercury/generator-mercury/generators/component/index.js:11:10)
at Environment.instantiate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:297:10)
at Environment.create (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/yeoman-environment/lib/environment.js:274:15)
at composeWith (/Users/zlandon/mercury/generator-mercury/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:614:26)
at module.exports.yeoman.generators.Base.extend.writing.app (/Users/zlandon/mercury/generator-mercury/generators/app/index.js:55:12)
at /Users/zlandon/mercury/generator-mercury/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:421:16
```

I believe I have an older version of node because of Outside Reasons, but the stack trace makes it feel Yo-specific anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update for yeoman-generator 1.0**

You need to pass both arguments and options in the same way:

```
this.composeWith(require.resolve('generator-mercury/component'), {
    optionName: 'my option',
    argumentName: 'an argument'
});
```

---

**For yeoman-generator 0.x**

There's a difference between `options` and `arguments`. You want:

```
this.composeWith('mercury:component', {
  args: [this.props.domain + 'Content', this.props.path + '/']
})
```

Comment: args has to be an array, rather than an object, but that was the direction I needed to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using yeoman-generator version 3.10.8

The only way I can pass arguments to a subgenerator is as follows:

```
this.composeWith('myGen:subGen', {
    arguments: ['value-for-first-arg']
});
```

Naming the arguments in the options object or using an array named args didn't work for me